# post request with C# using http and .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, http-post

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDpwl.jpg

I need a code snipped which I can use in a WPF application. It should send a post request to the server and return a JSON. Best would be if its working same as the print screen from chrome add-on postman above.  I tried to use uploading  form Data with HttpClient and uploading form data with WebRequest and it returned HTML page with an error.
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
public string PostJson(string url,string json)
        {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Writeline(string.Format("Request {0} Response Code {1} Resonse Status Description {2} Response From Server {3}",
                                          json, ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode,
                                         ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription, responseFromServer));
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }
```